# How to order N1QL results based on sub-array value of ARRAY_AGG

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have the following `N1QL` query:

```
 SELECT COUNT(tutorial) AS rows,
   ARRAY_AGG([age,fname])[0:3] AS res
      FROM tutorial
```

Can I order the child arrays of `res` by age value in `DESC`
I tried all of the below with noting change of the order

```
ORDER BY res[*].age DESC
ORDER BY res[*][age] DESC
ORDER BY age DESC
ORDER BY res.age DESC
```

Also you can execute the preceding query directly on following link to see the main structure of document and results http://query.pub.couchbase.com/tutorial/#3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question but I was facing the same problem.

My answer is specific to your need for sorting by **DESC** values.

ARRAY_SORT() only appears to work for assending order - there doesn't seem to be any option for DESC.

However, I found there is also ARRAY_REVERSE()

So when I combined these two I got the desired result, eg:

```
...
ARRAY_REVERSE( ARRAY_SORT( yourArrayNeeds ) ) AS result
...
```

Additionally, something else that tripped me up was that the item to sort by with ARRAY_SORT() needed to be alphabetically first in the array list. So, for example, if wishing to sort by 'item.submitted':

THIS **DIDN'T** SORT AS DESIRED:

```
...
ARRAY_SORT({ "submitted":item.submitted, "name":item.name }) AS result
...
```

THIS WORKED:

```
...
ARRAY_SORT({ "_submitted":item.submitted, "name":item.name }) AS result
...
```

...and then if you want a DESC order:

```
...
ARRAY_REVERSE( ARRAY_SORT({ "_submitted":item.submitted, "name":item.name }) ) AS result
...
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me (returns null). Do you know if this is supported in Couchbase 4.6? I  can't find a reasonable documentation for sorting array of objects, only for primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use ARRAY_SORT().

```
ARRAY_SORT( ARRAY_AGG( [ age, fname ] ) )[0:3] AS res ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna edit a previous response with the values that worked for me:

My answer is specific to your need for sorting by DESC values.

ARRAY_SORT() only appears to work for ascending order - there doesn't seem to be any option for DESC. However, I found there is also ARRAY_REVERSE(). In my query the ARRAY_REVERSE did not work.

THIS DIDN'T SORT AS DESIRED:

...
ARRAY_SORT({ "submitted":item.submitted, "name":item.name }) AS result
...

THIS WORKED:

...
ARRAY_SORT({ "_submitted":item.submitted, "name":item.name }) AS result
...

...and then if you want a DESC order:

...
ARRAY_SORT({ "_submitted":-item.submitted, "name":item.name }) AS result
...

Look at the minus sign prepended at the beginning of the ordering field for descending ordering.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Use  Subquery expression in the form clause

```
SELECT d.rows, 
     (SELECT RAW r FROM d.res AS r ORDER BY r.age DESC LIMIT 3) AS res
FROM (SELECT COUNT(tutorial) AS rows, ARRAY_AGG({age, name})AS res
      FROM tutorial) AS d;
```